# Breaking down equations like $2^22^{n-2}+(4 \cdot 3^{2})3^{n-2}=2^n+4 \cdot 3^n$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I'm looking at a proof in my book and it isn't clear to me how one goes from one step to the other in the following parts:

$$5(2^{n-1}+4 \cdot 3^{n-1})-6(2^{n-2}+4 \cdot 3^{n-2})=$$
$$(5 \cdot 2 - 6)2^{n-2}+(5 \cdot 4 \cdot 3 - 6 \cdot 4)3^{n-2}$$

and how

$$2^22^{n-2}+(4 \cdot 3^{2})3^{n-2}=$$
$$2^n+4 \cdot 3^n$$

The exponents in particular are confusing. Could someone break it down?

Comment: Use \cdot, $\cdot$, for multiplication instead of \bullet, $\bullet$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s

$$\begin{align*}
5(2^{n-1}+4\cdot3^{n-1})-6(2^{n-2}+4\cdot3^{n-2)}&=\Big(5\cdot2^{n-1}+\color{brown}{5\cdot4\cdot3^{n-1}}\Big)-\Big(6\cdot2^{n-2}+\color{brown}{6\cdot4\cdot3^{n-2}}\Big)\\
&=\Big(5\cdot2^{n-1}-6\cdot2^{n-2}\Big)+\Big(\color{brown}{5\cdot4\cdot3^{n-1}-6\cdot4\cdot3^{n-2}}\Big)\\
&=\Big(5\cdot2\cdot2^{n-2}-6\cdot2^{n-2}\Big)+\\
&\qquad+\Big(5\cdot4\cdot3\cdot3^{n-2}-6\cdot4\cdot3^{n-2}\Big)\\
&=(5\cdot2-6)2^{n-2}+(5\cdot4\cdot3-6\cdot4)3^{n-2}
\end{align*}$$

and

$$\begin{align*}
2^22^{n-2}+(4\cdot3^2)3^{n-2}&=2^{2+(n-2)}+4\cdot(3^2\cdot3^{n-2})\\
&=2^n+4\cdot3^{2+(n-2)}\\
&=2^n+4\cdot3^n\;.
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Thank you very much prof. Scott. You are an eminence!

Comment: @ProbabilityGuy: You’re very welcome.

Comment: Thank you! Quick question, if $a$ is an integer then is it always the case that $a^{n-1} = a \cdot a^{n-2} ? $

Comment: @Nolohice: It’s always the case that $a^x\cdot a^y=a^{x+y}$ no matter whether $a$ is an integer or not, so in particular $a^1\cdot a^{n-2}=a^{1+(n-2)}=a^{n-1}$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott OHHHHHH ok, everything just made a lot more sense. Thanks a ton!!

Comment: @Nolohice: You’re welcome!